# Updating gui binary arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, binary

The goal of this program is to read a binary file into an arraylist then display it in the gui window. There are 5 indexs and i use curIndex to update it. My problem I believe lays in the refreshUI(). I cant get it to update with the new the index. I also am not sure how to set the fields in the refresh. If you could point me in the right direction that would be awesome! thank YOU

```
 ArrayList<SalesAgent> salesForce = new ArrayList<>();
int curIndex = 0;

public RecordViewerPanel() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    initComponents();
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("sales.bin")));

    while (curIndex < 5) {

        String first = input.readUTF();
        String last = input.readUTF();
        double sales = input.readDouble();
        Date date = (Date) input.readObject();
        salesForce.add(new SalesAgent(first, last, sales, date));
        refreshUI();
    }


}

private void refreshUI() {
salesForce.get(curIndex);
lastTextField.setText(salesForce.getLast());
salesTextField.setText(String.valueOf(salesForce.getSales()));
dateTextField.setText(String.valueOf(salesForce.getDate()));

    jPanel2.repaint();
    curIndex++;

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


    nextButton.setText(">>");
    nextButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nextButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addComponent(firstTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addComponent(lastTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(salesTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addComponent(dateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(64, 64, 64))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(254, 254, 254)
                            .addComponent(previousButton)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(nextButton)))))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(jLabel6))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(firstTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lastTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(salesTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(dateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(previousButton)
                .addComponent(nextButton)))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void previousButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    if (curIndex > 0) {
        curIndex--;
    } else if (curIndex == 0) {
        curIndex = 4;
    }
    salesForce.get(curIndex);
    refreshUI();
}                                              

private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (curIndex < 4) {
        curIndex++;
    } else if (curIndex == 4) {
        curIndex = 0;
    }
    salesForce.get(curIndex);
    refreshUI();
}
```

Comment: `" I cant get it to update with the new the index. I also am not sure how to set the fields in the refresh."` -- What index? Which fields? Please explain how your current code works and how it's supposed to work, what each critical variable represents, what each critical method is supposed to do. A little bit of exposition will go a long way towards improving our understanding of your code and your problem, and will help you to get better answers quicker.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I updated it. I didnt realize I forgot to add the program goal

Comment: That helps, but at least for me is not quite enough. Again more explanation on the components of your program and their roles would help me a great deal.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I current display the name sales and date from the binary file from 3 of them. Only my next button works and it's not starting out on the first index. I have a recordviewerpanel recordviewerui and salesagent class

Comment: OK, better. Have you debugged your code? Do you know that the ArrayList holds the correct information? A simple for loop that reads out its contents after filling it would be enough for this.

Comment: Does your code even compile? ArrayList doesn't have methods like `getLast()`, `getSales()`, `getDate()`. And when you call `salesForce.get(curIndex)` you're not assigning the object returned to any variable, and so you're just throwing the data out.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Right now my code compiles and it shows 3 out of the 5 indexs. It's not showing the first or last index

Comment: I'm still confused as you're making calls on an ArrayList variable, like `salesForce.getLast()`, that should not be kosher that should result in compilation failure. Are you showing us your real code? Consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- please read the link.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels do you know why my previous button is not working??

Comment: I suspect that you're not handling your indices correctly (as per my answer). If my answer doesn't answer your question, then again, consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using "magic" numbers. Use your List's size to help you out. For example, this is bad:

```
private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (curIndex < 4) {
        curIndex++;
    } else if (curIndex == 4) {
        curIndex = 0;
    }
    salesForce.get(curIndex);
    refreshUI();
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
  curIndex++;
  curIndex %= salesForce.size(); // mod it by size of your List
  currentSalesAgent = salesForce.get(curIndex);
  // salesForce.get(curIndex); // this throws out the result returned by get(...)
  refreshUI();
}
```

Where currentSalesAgent is a SalesAgent field that your class uses to get the current guy's stats for display. In your class you'd declare

```
private SalesAgent currentSalesAgent;
```

Note that just calling `salseForce.get(curIndex);` does nothing of use since while the method does extract a SalesAgent item from the List, it is wasted since you don't assign the object returned to any variable. That is why I had:

```
currentSalesAgent = salesForce.get(curIndex);
```

Then in your refreshUI method, you use the currentSalesAgent:

```
// salesTextField.setText(String.valueOf(salesForce.getSales())); // this shouldn't compile!
salesTextField.setText(String.valueOf(currentSalesAgent.getSales()));
```

Again, this makes no sense to me whatsoever:

```
salesForce.getSales()
```

You're calling `getSales()` on an ArrayList, and ArrayList has no such method. How can this not cause a compilation error to occur?

---

**Edit**

I'm not sure that you fully understand me, and so I will try to spell out the issue. You have declared the `salesForce` variable as an ArrayList variable here:

```
ArrayList<SalesAgent> salesForce = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then here you appear to be making numerous calls on **this same variable** as if it were a SalesAgent object:

```
lastTextField.setText(salesForce.getLast());
salesTextField.setText(String.valueOf(salesForce.getSales()));
dateTextField.setText(String.valueOf(salesForce.getDate()));
```

Again, this cannot compile since ArrayList does not have any of these methods that you are calling, not unless you have a second *local* variable of the same name, `salesForce` that is in fact a SalesAgent object, and that shadows the class field, and one that you never show us that you've declared. If you're doing this, then **don't**. Your code is confusing enough as it is that you should not give two completely different variables that hold different types of objects the same name.

Comment: the getSales() is a double. I'm reading the double in the while loop

Comment: @alwill: Please see edit to answer. My answer recommendations still apply, and if you use them, will likely solve your problem. I suggest that you try to do this now.

Comment: its compiling and the only problem I have now is it gives me an error on the previous button but still runs.

Comment: @alwill: ***AGAIN***, are you **shadowing** a variable? Please re-read my latest edit. Again, your current code as displayed should not compile, and I'd like to know why. Sorry, but it's frustrating me, trying to get information out of you.